# Why doesn't a block element expand to fit parent's width if the element is in fixed position?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a fixed, horizontal navigation bar that stretches out across the screen horizontally. When I try to set its position to fixed, the unordered list element just takes up as much width as necessary to contain its content.

Since the unordered list is by default a block element, why doesn't it expand to full width?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 1):

Fixed-position elements take up as much space as their content, regardless of what their display is set to. To make it expand to fill the content, you need to set the `left` and `right` variables:

```
#myelement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This will make it fixed to the top, stretching the full width.